# HomeKit: Can I switch on/off my led lights without internet

Tags: wifi, homekit

I am curious about Apple Homekit and with the introduction of IKEA TRÅDFRI I can afford LED lights.

I know Apple HomeKit requires activating HomeKit with iCloud. I also know that Siri control requires Internet connection because Siri's recognition occurs within Apple's iCloud.

But can I switch on and off my led lights without any internet (but with wireless LAN, of course)? Or do I need to light my candles everytime I have no internet connection at home?